# How can I write an Automator action in bash with files and folders as arguments?

Tags: xcode, bash, automator

When I create a Automator action in XCode using Bash, all files and folder paths are printed to stdin.

How do I get the content of those files?
Whatever I try, I only get the filename in the output.

If I just select "Run shell script" I can select if I want everything to stdin or as arguments. Can this be done for an XCode project to?

It's almost easier to use Applescript, and let that run the Bash.

I tried something like

```
xargs | cat | MyCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the pipe between `xargs` and `cat` doing there? Try

```
xargs cat | MyCommand
```

or, better,

```
xargs -R -1 -I file cat "file" | MyCommand
```

to properly handle file names with spaces etc.

If, instead, you want MyComand invoked on each file,

```
local IFS="\n"
while read filename; do
  MyCommand < $filename
done
```

may also be useful.

Comment: Can you explain the options for xargs? I can't find them in man.

Comment: Huh? They are listed in my xargs man page.

The page lists August 2, 2004 as its date, so it should not look all that different on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

`read` will read lines from the script's stdin; just make  sure to set `$IFS` to something that won't interfere if the pathnames are sent without backslashes escaping any spaces:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
while read filename ; do
  echo "*** $filename:"
  cat -n "$filename"
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```